# Pipe to my own script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, grep, pipe

I've recently noticed this message from grep

```
"grep: warning: GREP_OPTIONS is deprecated; please use an alias or script"
```

I receive this warning because --color=always is defined in my .bashrc file.  AFAIK alias is impractical, because I want this to work on a pipe.  For example,

```
echo "a b c" |grep b
```

should highlight b.  Since an alias will not work, the other option presented is to make a script. But how do I make a script accept input from a pipe? In this case, I want the script append --color=always.

EDIT: An alias does work after all... and so does making a script. I have no idea what I was doing wrong with the alias method.  However, in making a script be sure to include $1 for input parameter.

For anyone else wanting to know how to pipe to your own script, in this example it worked for me by doing the following:

first make the script in a location in the path so its executable, e.g.

```
# ~/.bin/testgrep
grep --color=always $1
```

Now make the script executable, e.g.

```
chmod +x ~/.bin/testgrep
```

Now it should work!

Comment: What do you mean "an alias will not work"?  But also, what part of making a script accept input from a pipe is causing you difficulty?

Comment: An alias does work! Since it was in .bashrc I needed to reload the terminal.  Also, I was having difficulty because in the script I forgot to include the $1 for the input parameter

Comment: Never put `--color=always` in `GREP_OPTIONS`. This breaks many scripts that expect the output of `grep` to be lines from the file, without extra stuff. `echo "a b c" |grep --color=auto b` does highlight `b`.

Comment: an alias does work in a pipe....unless you are using something like `xargs grep`.  that fails because `xargs` forks `grep` by itself and does not use shell aliases.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`grep` (i.e., `/bin/grep`) will read from standard input
if it is invoked with no filename arguments. 
So it is simple to write a script that runs `grep` with input
from standard input — just invoke `grep` with no filename arguments. 
But `grep` must be given (at least) one *PATTERN* argument (or equivalent). 
An extremely inflexible way to do that,
which is unlikely to be very useful in real life,
is to hard-code a search string (pattern) into your grep script; e.g.,

```
#!/bin/sh
grep --color=always cat
```

which could be used in the context

```
ps | mygrep
```

and probably not much else.  A *slightly* more flexible script
might use an environment variable as the search string:

```
#!/bin/sh
grep --color=always $USER
```

which could be used in the context

```
ps -ef | mygrep
```

and probably not much else.  The only reasonable, realistic, robust solution
is to allow the user of the script
to supply a search string as a command-line argument:

```
#!/bin/sh
grep --color=always $1
```

which could be used in the context

```
dmesg | mygrep TCP
```

and might actually be fairly useful.

Well, maybe I should say *somewhat* useful. 
This breaks down fairly quickly,
as you might need multiple arguments to specify the search parameters:

```
mygrep -i tcp                   Case-insensitive search; find tcp, TCP, Tcp, etc.
mygrep -v bash                  Find everything except bash.
mygrep -e cat -e dog            Find every line that contains cat or dog.
mygrep -f wordlist              Search strings are in a file.
```

So the second draft of our script might be:

```
#!/bin/sh
grep --color=always $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9
```

which could handle any of the above examples.  As an extra bonus,
this doesn’t need to be used to read the standard input; we can say

```
mygrep -i path .bashrc
```

and it will run

```
grep --color=always -i path .bashrc
```

But we’re not done yet!  Consider

```
mygrep  "cat food"  "shopping list.txt"
```

which will run

```
grep --color=always cat food shopping list.txt
```

which will (try to) search for `cat` in three files:
`food`, `shopping`, and `list.txt`.  OK, we can handle that by saying

```
#!/bin/sh
grep --color=always "$1" "$2"
```

but

```
#!/bin/sh
grep --color=always "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6" "$7" "$8" "$9"
```

isn’t a good answer; it will turn

```
mygrep  "cat food"  "shopping list.txt"
```

into

```
grep --color=always  "cat food"  "shopping list.txt"  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "" ""
```

which will do what you want, but will also issue seven error messages.

So, what to do, what to do? 
Oh, wait; I have a sledgehammer in my closet:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$1" = "" ]
then
    printf "%s\n" "error: mygrep must be run with at least one argument."
elif [ "$2" = "" ]
then
    grep --color=always "$1"
elif [ "$3" = "" ]
then
    grep --color=always "$1" "$2"
elif [ "$4" = "" ]
then
    grep --color=always "$1" "$2" "$3"
elif [ "$5" = "" ]
then
    grep --color=always "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4"
elif [ "$6" = "" ]
then
    grep --color=always "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5"
elif [ "$7" = "" ]
then
    grep --color=always "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6"
elif [ "$8" = "" ]
then
    grep --color=always "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6" "$7"
elif [ "$9" = "" ]
then
    grep --color=always "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6" "$7" "$8"
else
    grep --color=always "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6" "$7" "$8" "$9"
fi
```

Right.

1. That’s laughably impractical.
2. Even that fails for

   ```
   mygrep  -e cat  -e dog  -e fish  file1  file2  file3  file4
   ```

   because it has more than nine arguments! 
   And, while this situation may seem unlikely, the same problem occurs with

   ```
   mygrep  bird  *
   ```

   if there are more than eight (non-hidden) files in the current directory.

#### So, what to do, what to do?

## TL;DR

If you look in [bash(1)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?bash)
under **Special Parameters**,
you’ll see that `$@` expands to the list of positional parameters,
starting from one.  When the expansion occurs within double quotes,
each parameter expands to a separate word. 
That is, `"$@"` is equivalent to `"$1"` `"$2"` …
(as implemented in the long script, above,
but not limited to the first nine). 
So, the way to write a script to wrap
(i.e., act as a front-end for) some command, acting like an alias, is

```
#!/bin/sh
grep --color=always "$@"
```

Answer (score 2):

An alias will work.  I have `grep` aliased to `grep --color=auto`:

```
% which grep
grep: aliased to grep --color=auto
```

And piping to grep has the behavior you desire:

[image]